# Fill up a column in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0], [2,2] ], columns=('feature1', 'feature2'))
```

Now I would like to add an extra column

```
df['c'] = ""
```

And then loop trought the data.frame to fill up column C with the contents of both feature 1 and feature 2

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    subject = row["feature1"]
    content = row["feature2"]
    row["C"] = subject, content
```

However if I print the data frame now. Something seems to go wrong cause column C is empty.

Comment: Sorry what are you trying to set here? Are you trying to set a tuple? change the last row to this: `df.loc[index,"c"] = subject, content`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to build a tuple out of two columns, be explicit and keep it simple:

```
df['c'] = df.apply(tuple, axis=1)

df
Out[7]: 
   feature1  feature2       c
0         0         0  (0, 0)
1         2         2  (2, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

EdChum has you covered in the comments for how to fix your approach - you should be using [`.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for indexing. However can achieve the same much more simply and without having to resort to row iteration by using `zip`.

```
In[43]: df['c'] = list(zip(df.feature1, df.feature2))
in[44]: df
Out[44]: 
   feature1  feature2       c
0         0         0  (0, 0)
1         2         2  (2, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.assign(c=df.set_index(['feature1', 'feature2']).index.to_series().values)
```

Comment: I'm on par +/- 5% for both methods if I take into account the assignment: you pay a lot to go from list to Series before assigning to 'c' apprently. Also  , without assignment I find only a 10x factor. pandas 0.19.1 python 3.5.2 64bits.

Comment: @Boud `True`... I'll delete timings until I put a more appropriate comparison.  I got what I wanted though.  Mitch undeleted his answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You never updated the original column. You just updated a variable named row. But for ease of remembering code (not the most efficient obviously):

```
df['C'] = zip(df.feature1, df.feature2)
```

Comment: this works in python 2 but not python 3.  @Mitch's answer works for both.